# ckeditor upload images doesn't work with cloudflare

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, cloudflare, fckeditor

I use CKEditor to upload images - click image icon, select "Upload" tab in "Image Properties" Dialog, choose image and click "Send it to the server". After that I see endless progress bar and nothing happens.

I open "development tools" in browser and see 405 error for fck_image.html file.

Also I have found that site uses Cloudflare and there is error A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://ajax.cloudflare.com/.../cloudflare.min.js, is invoked via document.write

and maybe for this reason fck_image.js which set action = "asp file for upload" doesn't work and as a result it posts to fck_image.html

Does anybody know how to configure cloudflare or fckeditor to work together ok?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the uploader gets blocked as a bad browser. One of two things will fix this:

- Whitelist your IP in CloudFlare.
- Set a page rule on the url that does the uploading to bypass security.